# highcharts column charts show sum single 0 when entire column data total is 0

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am creating column charts using highchart its displaying 0 if all of the fields are 0. I want to display single 0 per category if all data in that particular category is 0 (i.e., total is 0) 
 Please refer   http://jsfiddle.net/rutup/6hxPU/18/

```
  function createBarChart(source, title, placeHolderId, sideText, xColumnValue) {

$('#' + placeHolderId).highcharts({
    credits: { enabled: false },
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    exporting: { enabled: false },
    title: {
        text: false
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: xColumnValue
    },

    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 20,
        borderWidth: 0,
        enabled: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        minRange: 0,
        lineWidth: 0,
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        title: {
            text: sideText
        },
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
    stackLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        style: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            color: 'gray'
        },
         formatter: function () {
                    return calcAntiLog(this.y) == null ? 0 :               calcAntiLog(this.y);
    }
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                this.series.name + ': ' + (calcAntiLog(this.y) == null ? 0 : calcAntiLog(this.y));
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {


            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
                , formatter: function () {
                    return calcAntiLog(this.y) == null ? 0 : calcAntiLog(this.y);
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: source
});

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If that is enough to pick the middle column, and show a zero above, then something like this would do the trick: 
http://jsfiddle.net/6hxPU/20/

Of course if you have even number of columns, the zero won't be centered. That case I think the best you can do is to find where to put the zero, based on the column heights and draw it directly with `Highcharts.Renderer()`.

Comment: this seems to be a bug in the latest highcharts (v3.0.10). if I try with v3.0.9 the labels are there. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/6hxPU/25/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use loop on each point, and remove stackLabel's SVG object.